# Trying to get `$FOO =~ bar|baz` to work in Bash and Zsh

Tags: bash, regex, zsh

I'm trying to get a simple `if` statement working in both Zsh and Bash but I can't find something to work with both.

```
# this works with Zsh
if [[ "$TERM_PROGRAM" =~ iTerm\|Apple_Terminal ]]; then echo apples; fi

# this works with Bash
if [[ "$TERM_PROGRAM" =~ iTerm|Apple_Terminal ]]; then echo apples; fi
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is one case where putting it in a variable first helps.  This works for me in both zsh and bash:

```
pattern='^iTerm|Apple_Terminal$'
if [[ "$TERM_PROGRAM" =~ $pattern ]]; then echo apples; fi
```

(Note: I added anchors to the pattern, to avoid matching things like "not_iTerm".)

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find a way to escape the regex that worked on both Bash and Zsh.

Here's a workaround I am using:

```
echo "$TERM_PROGRAM" | egrep -q 'iTerm|Apple_Terminal'
```